# Information Visualization: which parameters should a data scientist plot to best explain the work behind a Neural Network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, dataset, visualization, matplotlib

I'm a beginner in the field and I wrote and trained my first Convolutional Neural Network from scratch. I would like to know what types of graphics and parameters a data scientist uses to plot to explain a neural network in the best possibile and mathematical way. As far as I know I use to plot loss and accuracy graphics using matplotlib.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to explain your findings but associating the target with the inputs provided is tough and only a few architectures like Decision Trees do it well.

- If you are trying to answer the question "why is my neural network missing out on a few samples from my validation set?" then its going to be a tough but possible road ahead. There are many good resources to [interpretable machine learning](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/)
- If you are trying to compare your model's (CNN) performance to other
  architectures on the same data set, then looking at [Receiver Operator Characteristics](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-auc-roc-curve-68b2303cc9c5) is a good point to start.
- If you're having an unbalanced data set, then the [F1 Score](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjkwP375ODtAhWc_XMBHQuCBOgQFjAEegQIBRAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmachinelearningmastery.com%2Fclassification-accuracy-is-not-enough-more-performance-measures-you-can-use%2F&usg=AOvVaw1qpddIEXL-TaDeRaiw4SME) is a good thing to have look at. Being a classification problem (which is my assumption from your question), you can indicate the performance by a [variety of derived quantities.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall)

Answer (score 0):

You can plot the **Confusion matrix** of your model to show the number of true positive, true negative, false positive, false negative.

> Code for Confusion matrix

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
confusion_matrix(y_true,y_pred)
```

For more details on confusion matrix refer to [confusion matrix](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html)

The confusion matrix can be plotted using seaborn heatmap.

> Code to plot Confusion matrix

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.heatmap(confusion_matrix, annot=True)
```

for more details on *heatmap* refer to [Seaborn Heatmap](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)